# Bootstrap Modal submit button not working with DeleteView in Django 2.2

Tags: django, django-models, bootstrap-4, django-views

I am learning Django 2.2 and using a little bit of Bootstrap 4 to help with the front end. I have a Model created which stores some user information like first name and last name. I have created a `DeleteView` class which is supposed to delete entries from the database using the `ID`. Everything works fine as is. But if I try to implement the DeleteView class using a Bootstrap modal window, nothing seems to happen even if I click the submit button. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I read in another thread here in Stackoverflow that we need to include the button inside a form which I have done too. But it still doesn't delete the entry. Below is all the code required.

**Note -** I have placed the `Delete` button inside the `contacts_view.html` file. The `contacts_delete.html` file is exactly the same. My idea is to provide the user to not just view the details but also update or even delete the specific entry. When I click on the Delete button, the modal pop up window appears. But when I click on the 'Confirm' button, the entry does not get deleted as required.

Please let me know how to proceed with this.

***contacts_view.html / contacts_delete.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container" style="width: 500px">
        <div>
            <div class="list-group" style="color: black">
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action my-1" style="background-color: wheat">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            First Name
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{ object.first_name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action my-1" style="background-color: wheat">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            last Name
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            {{ object.last_name }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="border-top text-center my-4 pt-3">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger ml-2" href="{% url 'contacts-delete' object.id %}" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: whitesmoke; color: dimgray">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Contact</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body text-left">
                            form
                            <p>Do you really want to delete {{ object.first_name }} {{ object.last_name }}?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'contacts-delete' object.id %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                <button class="btn btn-outline-warning ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="{% url 'contacts-delete' object.id %}" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                            </form>

                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="{% url 'contacts-view' object.id %}" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

***views.py***

```
from .models import Contact
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.views.generic import DetailView, DeleteView

class ContactDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contacts/contacts_view.html'

class ContactDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'contacts_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contacts-browse')
```

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Contact(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

***urls.py***

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ContactDetailView, ContactDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('view/<int:pk>/', ContactDetailView.as_view(), name='contacts-view'),
    path('view/<int:pk>/delete/', ContactDeleteView.as_view(), name='contacts-delete'),
]
```